# Protractor onPrepare() native example from GitHub

Tags: javascript, github, protractor

Example below is taken from [Protractor GitHub](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js). Since I'm new to protractor I'd like to understand everything thoroughly.

```
onPrepare: function() {
browser.driver.get(env.baseUrl + '/ng1/login.html');

browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('Jane');
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('1234');
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('clickme')).click();

// Login takes some time, so wait until it's done.
// For the test app's login, we know it's done when it redirects to
// index.html.
return browser.driver.wait(function() {
  return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
    return /index/.test(url);
  });
}, 10000);
}
```

So I don't entirely understand what last 3 return statements do? Especially this line

> return /index/.test(url);

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two of those functions are explained in the [Protractor API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api)

[getCurrentUrl](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl) is self explanatory, it retrieves the current URL.

[wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) is also fairly self explanatory, it waits for a  promise, condition object, or a function to evaluate as a condition

The final one, `.test`, is a javascript [regular expression method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) that "executes a search for a match"

So that whole block just says wait for the current URL to pass the condition of `.test` (that condition being that the URL contains "index")